# Silverlight DataGrid Refresh Between Xaml Files

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I have a Page.xaml file and a AddNewProject.xaml.  In the Page.xaml file I have a ProjectDetailsDataGrid and a button to add a new Project.  When I click on the Add New Project button the AddNewProject.xaml file becomes visible for the user to enter new project information.

I am having a problem trying to refresh the ProjectDetailsDataGrid (on the Page.xaml page) to display the new info. entered from the AddNewProject.xaml page.

Is there anyway to accomplish refreshing a datagrid between two seperate xaml files?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use data binding to have both of the controls bind to the same data source - You will also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your data source.
See [this tutorial on Data Binding](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials/databinding.aspx) it is a new topic to you